# ajax post truncating leading zero's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: 'http://example.com/jambo',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: String(' ' + $('InputTextBox').val()),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        var errmsg = JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert("message: " + errmsg);
    }
});
```

The value in InputTextBox has leading 0's but when this is posted to the url the leading 0's are truncated.

Comment: What do you get as the post body when you view the request in the network tab? are you sure this is a client-side issue?

Comment: also, `contentType: "application/json",` doesn't seem right, you're not sending json, you're sending a string. (which is likely where the problem is originating from.) most json parsers will convert the string `0005` to `5`, and the string `"0005"` to `"0005"`

Comment: `String(123)` gives `'123'` but `String(0123)` (or more 0s in front) gives `'83'` because it is interpreted as octal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending json to a server, you should use the built-in JSON.stringify method to create json rather than creating it manually.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: 'http://example.com/jambo',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify($('InputTextBox').val()),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        var errmsg = JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert("message: " + errmsg);
    }
});
```

This will result in sending `"0005"` instead of `0005`, which when parsed, will be converted back into the string rather than a number which will lose the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the code on this page;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: '/test',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: String(' 004'),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        var errmsg = JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert("message: " + errmsg);
    }
});
```

obviously alerts the 404 page but in the net tab of Chrome and Firefox shows the data is sent correctly ' 004'.
Please re ask your question with the code on the server, as the issue is not client side.
As Kevin B noted ' 004' is a type numeric according to the [JSON specification](http://json.org/)
so if you want the zeros and want to use a JSON library on the server sent the data as '" 004"' or use JSON.stringify(' 004').

Comment: If you send ` 004` to a server with the application/json contentType, the server should convert it to the value `4` assuming it's following json specs. (if it doesn't fail on the invalid number)

Answer (score 0):

Removing `contentType: "application/json",` in my ajax call fixed the issue for me

**Reason:-**

`contentType: "application/json",` will get the values first converted to numbers as it tries to parse your data to JSON. Removing this line from your ajax call will stop the parsing of data.

**Note :** The parsing will happen not only in your data you are `POST`ing, but also it will parse the queryStrings in your URL when you use `GET` method